# UDF to randomly assign values based on different probabilities

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I would like to create a UDF to randomly assign values based on different probabilities.

In the following example depending of the value returned by rand:

- 0 to 0.5 the value should be A (50% probability)
- 0.8 to 1 the value should be B (20% probability)
- anything else the value should be c (30% probability)

`val names = Array("A", "B", "C")`

```
val allocate = udf((p: Double) => {
    if(p < 0.5) names(0)
    else if (p > 0.8) names(1)
    else names(2)})

val test = sqlContext.range(0, 100).select(($"id"),(round(abs(rand),2)).alias("val"), allocate(abs(rand)).alias("name"))
`
```

However when I print the result the names are not assigned based on the rules defined in the UDF.

```
+---+----+----+
| id| val|name|
+---+----+----+
|  0|0.17|   C| => should be A
|  1|0.12|   A|
|  2|0.36|   A|
|  3|0.56|   B|
|  4|0.82|   A|=> should be C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing unexpected going on here. You call `rand` function twice so you get two different random values.

Either provide the same seed for both calls:

```
sqlContext.range(0, 100)
  .select(
    $"id", 
    abs(rand(1)).alias("val"),
    allocate(abs(rand(1))).alias("name") 
  )
```

or reuse the value:

```
sqlContext.range(0, 100)
  .withColumn("val", abs(rand))
  .withColumn("name", allocate($"val"))
```